# VirtualBox Linux Unable to mount android device

Tags: android, linux, virtualbox

I have setup Mint in VirtualBox, and use the GUI.
I followed the instructions to install the GuestAdditions (with root privilege), I run VBoxLinuxAdditions.run and everything is working like a charm. My android device is detected right away.

However, as soon as after I restart Linux, I get a message Unable to Mount LGE Android Phone, the phone keeps trying to be connected without success and pops up this message.

Then if I install again the guest additions then it works.

How could I do in order to get the android device working right away after reboot?

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me something similar in ubuntu, in my case I opened it without privileges, what I did was open the virtualbox with root privileges.

Then I realized I had to add my user to the plugdev group: "$ sudo add $ USER plugdev"

I hope that we can help.